# vertical scrollbar not showing in flexbox children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the top panel to have no scrollbars and the two bottom panels to have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

The horizontal scrollbars for the bottom panels do not work.

If I delete the top div, the scrollbars behave just fine.

```html
<style>
  * {
    font-size: 200px;
  }

  html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .splitter {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .left {
    background-color: bisque;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  .right {
    background-color: rgb(67, 228, 62);
    overflow: scroll;
  }
  .top {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
<div class="top">
  top
</div>
<div class="splitter">
  <div class="left">
    this is panel 1
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    this is panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `height` and `width` of 100% try `100vh` and `100vw`

Comment: So you want the entire page to scroll without a scroll bar then 2 sides are scrolling? Am i understanding this right? Does your top needs to scroll too? your scroll won't work since your html and body overflow is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it working, you might be able to tweak it to your liking. I think this type of layout in isolation is terrible as it's not responsive to the content/device.

```css
* {
  font-size: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.splitter {
  max-height: 90vh;
  flex: 50% 1 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left,
.right {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.left {
  background-color: bisque;
}

.right {
  background-color: rgb(67, 228, 62);
}

.top {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 50% 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  top
</div>
<div class="splitter">
  <div class="left">
    this is panel 1
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    this is panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i see that you used flexbox for both the body and the splitter.thanks that works. almost, i just changed a bit: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yigalirani/flexbox2/master/index.html